# {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I want to fetch data from from facebook using python and facebook graph API. But when I tried I got the above error. My code is given below.

```
import requests
token='V4NzPkk55gXZAPr4FFTwgJGyosZBafEujZCeyebq4UZANIac226ZBcxgC7zTD9f57'
me = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?access_token'+token
me1 = requests.get(me)
print(me1.text)
```

What is the issue happened for me?

Comment: Without knowing anything about Facebook's API, I would suggesting adding an `=` to the end of your string: `me = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me?access_token='+token`

Comment: Great sir.It  worked for me.And they asked me to change the token also.Now it is working well.Sorry for thew silly mistake